# how to insert % in matrix

Tags: r, data-manipulation

I have a matrix and I want to multiply each cell with 100, insert "%" next to it and have a matrix at the end.

```
    mtcars1 <- as.matrix(head(mtcars))
class(mtcars1)
mtcars1.per <- paste0(round(prop.table((mtcars1)), digits=2)*100,  "%")
```

expected results in matrix form:

```
#                    mpg   cyl  disp      hp  drat  wt qsec vs  am   gear carb
#Mazda RX4         "1%" "0%" "7%"  "5%" "0%" "0%" "1%" "0%" "0%" "0%" "0%"
```

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Are those values correct based on the `prop.table`.  For me the `prop.table`from your code is not giving 11000%

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we need a `matrix` at the end, make sure the assign is with `[]` to preserve the attributes

```
mtcars1.per <- mtcars1
mtcars1.per[] <- paste0(round(prop.table((mtcars1)), digits=2)*100,  "%")
```